# I want to write a shell script which reads strings until a string is introduced twice

Tags: shell

I am new to shell scripts, but I tried the following:

```
#!/bin/sh

declare -a s
read string1
s[0] = string1

while ((a<=2))
do
    read string2
    for i in "${s[@]}"
    do
         if $i=string2 
         then
             a=3
             exit 1
         fi
    done
    s[@+1]=string2
done
```

It does not work, and I am not even sure that I need to use arrays. Any help would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just a few errors. Corrected below

```
declare -a s
read -p "enter a value: " string1
s[0]=$string1      # must not have spaces around `=`
                   # must use `$` to get the *value* of a variable

while true         # infinite loop
do
    read -p "enter a value: " string2
    for i in "${s[@]}"
    do
         if [[ "$i" = "$string2" ]]   # how to test string equality
         then
             break    # break the loop
         fi
    done
    s+=("$string2")      # append a value to the array
done
```

Comment: I get an error when I try to run this.First it says that: "declare: not found" and after I type in the first string I get the error: s[o]=home(the string i introduced) : not found, and on the next line: Syntax error: word unexpected(expecting")")

Comment: You need to execute this with `bash`, not `sh`